# import different version of library in Java with NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 7.2 as IDE, Java 7 and I have a lot of issues with different versions of a library.

Let's call the library in question as Lib (JAR file).

I have to realize a project A in Java, that uses package B and package C. Now B has dependency on Lib_v1.jar and C has dependency on Lib_v2.jar. Lib_v1 and Lib_v2 are 2 version of the same library and they aren't compatible, nevertheless they have a lot of class in common, so it is possible that a class can be loaded from a different version of the 
library.

How can I manage this issue?

Comment: As outlined in the existing answers, there is no easy solution, if your project A has to run in one virtual machine as asimple application. If your project can be implemented as two components running in two virtual machines, or if its dependencies B and C can be deployed as two separate web applications, and then A can communicate with them when they are deployed that way (e.g., with a RESTful approach) you could get out of the tangle, since you'd then have a chance of having separate, independent classpaths. Which way is best depends on the actual libaries and project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no real way to solve this problem. Even if you put both JAR files into the classpath one will get picked up by preference to the other.

If the library versions are not backwards compatible and the people who made the change didn't change package or something then you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Unfortunately the library version is not backwards compatible

Comment: There isn't much you can do then, those two libraries aren't compatible with each other :(. Try and find an updated version of B that is compatible with the new version or an old version of A that is compatible with the old one.

Answer (score -1):

isn't lib_v2 backwards compatible ? So you could use only lib_v2.jar ?

I saw a googlecode project(jar jar) which seems to solve your problem, have a look:  https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/

Comment: Unluckly the versions aren't compatible

Comment: why don't you recompile the lib_v1.jar, with different package name, lets say from "org.foo" to "org.foo.bar", and you could use the fully qualified name of its classes in B

Comment: This is not a solution. It should be posted as a comment.

Comment: @Borodin I cannot add comment since I have less then 50 reputation :(